# Get value from modal window

Tags: java, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have a problem with get a value of field from modal window.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <form th:action="@{/groups/add}" method="post">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addModal">Add group</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Group Name</label> <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" id="addName" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Faculty</label> <select
                                class="form-control">
                                <option th:value=0>Faculty not assign</option>
                                <option th:each="faculty : ${faculties}" th:value="${faculty.id}"
                                    th:utext="${faculty.name}">Faculty</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

In browser when I use "add" method, I can choose any Faculty from table, it works OK, but when I press button "save", only name returned to Controller and no info about faculty that was chosen. What I missed?

Comment: Do you have class represent these attributes?

Comment: yes, of course. I see every record from database via select

Comment: Ok, please check the answer

Comment: Did you try the answer? any luck!

Comment: Are you using Spring (and the [Spring dialect](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect) of Thymeleaf)? Or are you using the [standard](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#introducing-thymeleaf) Thymeleaf dialect?

Comment: For a `<select>` input (a drop-down list) you can use the `th:selected` attribute to capture the selected value.

Comment: @andrewjames th:selected show current value for entity, when we get entity from database, or not?

Comment: @sc0der do I need to have DTO as POJO? Because now its Group(int id, String name, Faculty faculty)

Comment: Notes: (1) Yes `<select>` is for showing current value. Sorry - not relevant for creating new records. (2) Are you using Spring dialect of Thymeleaf? (3) Is the data being sent from the browser? See browser tools (usually F12, then the network tab). (4) Just as a test, try moving the `<form>...</form>` section to _inside_ the `<div class="modal-dialog">...</div>` section. This is in case the modal structure (e.g. maybe a frame?) is interfering with data submission. Unlikely - but worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem- I forget to give a name for field where facultyId is stored. 
Here was error:

```
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Faculty</label> 
<select class="form-control">
```

Correct:

```
<label for="faculyId" class="col-form-label">Faculty</label> 
<select class="form-control" id="addFaculty" name="facultyId">
```